# Site to Site and Point to Site VPN simultaneously on Azure

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, site-to-site-vpn, point-to-site-vpn

I'm trying to get P2S and S2S to work at the same time. They are working fine individually but when I try to make it work together it falls short. Windows 2012 R2 server and a USG110 Zyxel firewall.

The errors im getting in the logs are "The cookie pair is: x / y", "Send[INVALID MAJOR VERSION]", "Major version numbers are different".

Is what I'm trying to do possible with one Virtual network gateway, or do I need 2 for different purposes?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi Simon P, when you created your Virtual Network Gateway on Azure did you create a Route or Policy based Gateway? P2S and S2S will work on the same Virtual Network Gateway but only if you have created a Route based gateway

Comment: Hi Simon P, P2S connections can be used in conjunction with S2S connections through the same VPN gateway, as long as all of the configuration requirements for both connections are compatible.

Comment: I solved it! I was running IKEv1 instead of IKEv2, it apparently has to be IKEv2 in a routebased environment.

Comment: @SimonP you can answer your own question and mark it as an answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a route-based system (Point-to-Site), you need to use IKEv2 and not IKEv1. IKEv1 Doesn't support point-to-site, only site-to-site.